# How to change the password of Gmail in CLI?

Tags: gmail

How to change the password of Gmail in CLI ?

That is, after:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect pop.gmail.com:995
```

What command should I type?

Some says we can't in CLI.

Is it true ?

And Is it also true for other email service provider ?

Comment: You can't change your password just using SMTP. Use the web interface.

Answer (score 2):

The only way this is possible trough CLI is using browser like 
[w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/).

It is not exactly one line command solution, but is the only one without graphical environment as far as I know.

However you haven't stated what OS you are using so I am not sure if you will have it in the repos or you need to install it manually. But if you use Linux chances are that it is available in the repos.

This is what gmail looks like:

[image: w3m gmail]

You can navigate with arrows, and "click" hyperlinks with enter. If you need more information how to use it you can refer to the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/w3m).